# Sort index of pivot dataframe in specific user defined order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

This i my `dfe` :-

```
ID        CATEG  LEVEL  COLS           VALUE   COMMENTS 
1         A      PG    Apple           428    comment1 
1         A      CD    Apple           175    comment1 
1         C      PG    Apple           226    comment1 
1         C      AB    Apple           884    comment1 
1         C      CD    Apple           288    comment1 
1         B      PG    Apple           712    comment1 
1         B      AB    Apple           849    comment1 
2         B      CD    Apple           376    comment1 
2         C      None  Orange          591    comment1 
2         B      CD    Orange          135    comment1 
2         D      None  Orange          423    comment1 
2         A      AB    Orange          1e13   comment1 
2         D      PG    Orange          1e15   comment2
```

Im creating a `pivot` like this :

```
df=pd.pivot_table(dfe,index=['ID','CATEG','LEVEL'],columns='COLS',values=['VALUE'])
```

I want the df to be written to excel in specific order of the index `CATEG` and `LEVEL`
I want to order `CATEG` of df according to another df `order` :-

```
sl set
1   C
2   B
3   A
4   D
```

And `LEVEL` in this order:- `PG AB CD`. This order wont change and remain constant for all `dfe` df,but `CATEG` changes and needs to be set according to `order` df only.

```
          Apple     Orange      
CATEG   PG  AB  CD  PG  AB  CD
C                       
B                       
A                       
D
```

I tried many things but missing out something, as `dfe` gets converted to different order just while writing to excel :-

```
df= pd.merge(df,order[['sl','set']].rename({'set':'CATEG'}, axis=1), how='left',on='CATEG')
df = df.sort_values(['sl']).drop('sl', axis=1)  

with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx',options={'nan_inf_to_errors': True}) as writer :
        df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x.dropna(how='all', axis=1).to_excel(writer,sheet_name=str(x.name),na_rep=0,index=True))
writer.save()
```

It prints in its own order even after changing how do i fix it? Also Im unable to write the scientifc format as a number even after trying various aproaches like `float_format="%.0f"` or converting to `object` or `pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.0f' % x)`, is there a fix for it, I have to manually change number formatting in excel to get a umber for few columns

Comment: What is the `CATEG` of the last row?

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you keeping the ID and Comments columns?

Comment: @Scope, you have multiple questions in one and I just used `to_excel` instead of `ExcelWriter`, but this should solve your core issues and get really close. The rows and column are sorted as desired. Kindly accept as answer and upvote if helpful. Thank you!

Comment: No the formatting was not proper so I had to change it ,maybe you saw it then.I have not changed anything. I want to understand the order `LEVEL` part

Comment: @Scope it was incorrect earlier but the output is now exactly what you you have shown in the fourth code snippet.

Comment: I havent changed any data, only added formatting as soneone pointed out last row was missing `CATEG`

Comment: @Scope what is incorrect about my solution? Thoroughly answering questions like these that have multiple questions within them is time-consuming. FYI I have downvoted, because I have matched your output, and you are not being clear about what is still incorrect with the answer after a lot of time helping you get to the solution. The rows and columns are sorted in the exact correct order now.

Comment: Hi if you run the code without doing any sorting ( right from df to write to excel you can see that the `LEVEL` is not in order in the df. You have taken a dataframe where `LEVEL` is in orer and displayed it which I can do if that the cae.. but the `df` you have taken is incorrect

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can sort values by merging in columns from dataframes with the order desired and then drop the columns later. Then, create a pivot table, paying to the attention of the order of you are setting as `index` and `columns` -- otherwise that may mess up the order if you order `s1` and `s2` columns incorrectly.

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'s1': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4}, 'set': {0: 'C', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'D'}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'s2': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'LEVEL': {0: 'PG', 1: 'AB', 2: 'CD'}})
dfe = (dfe[['ID','CATEG','LEVEL','COLS','VALUE']]
        .merge(df1.rename({'set' : 'CATEG'}, axis=1),how='left',on='CATEG')
        .merge(df2, how='left', on='LEVEL'))
dfe = pd.pivot_table(dfe,index=['ID','s1','CATEG'],columns=['COLS','s2','LEVEL'],values=['VALUE'])
dfe.columns = dfe.columns.droplevel([0,2])
dfe = dfe.reset_index().drop(('s1',''), axis=1).set_index('CATEG')
dfe
Out[1]: 
COLS  ID  Apple                      Orange                     
LEVEL        PG     AB     CD            PG            AB     CD
CATEG                                                           
C      1  226.0  884.0  288.0           NaN           NaN    NaN
B      1  712.0  849.0    NaN           NaN           NaN    NaN
A      1  428.0    NaN  175.0           NaN           NaN    NaN
B      2    NaN    NaN  376.0           NaN           NaN  135.0
A      2    NaN    NaN    NaN           NaN  1.000000e+13    NaN
D      2    NaN    NaN    NaN  1.000000e+15           NaN    NaN
```

OR without `ID` in your pivot table (just change the line of code below and run above code with this change):

```
dfe = pd.pivot_table(dfe,index=['s1','CATEG'],columns=['COLS','s2','LEVEL'],values=['VALUE'])

COLS   Apple                      Orange                     
LEVEL     PG     AB     CD            PG            AB     CD
CATEG                                                        
C      226.0  884.0  288.0           NaN           NaN    NaN
B      712.0  849.0  376.0           NaN           NaN  135.0
A      428.0    NaN  175.0           NaN  1.000000e+13    NaN
D        NaN    NaN    NaN  1.000000e+15           NaN    NaN
```

Then, just use:

```
dfe.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

[image]

Comment: The order should be `CBAD` and I cannot drop duplicates as each row is unique

Comment: Which step sets `LEVEL` on order of `PG AB CD`

Comment: @Scope yes, I forgot that using `.unstack()` changes the order again. I have also excluded `drop_duplicates()`

Comment: Yes, the output data from the last line of code `df` is how the data will look.

Comment: i didnt get you after the Pivot befoe writing to excel right? Also where is the code for setting order as `PG AB CD`

Comment: You have taken `PG AB CD` in orer on your dataframe, whereas i fyou see on my df its not ordered which is what i need to order

Comment: your question states: "And LEVEL in this order:- PG AB CD" I have put in that specific order. Not sure what you mean.